# Https cancelling clean url

Tags: .htaccess

I'm having an issue with my htaccess file.  I'm able to get https working (green lock and all), but I can't get my clean url to work.  I'm trying to have my page https://www.mystore.com/product.php?id=1, to become https://www.mystore.com/product/1 . What I have now, just keeps throwing me a 404.

Here's my code...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://www.mystore.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

#Rewrite for product.php?id=1
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+) product.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

I've been searching for days and seen a lot of similar questions here on stackoverflow, but they're all a bit too specific for me to figure out how to apply it in my case.  All the same, I've tried a ton of permutations, including getting rid of the "L" after the https rewrite, but I always get a 404 error. 
The closest I came is when I tried...

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+) https://www.mystore.com/product.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

..., this took my product/1 link and delivered me to product.php?id=1. Completely backwards and not what I was looking for, however it didn't give me a 404 error. It took me to the correct page (with the wrong url).

I have a feeling there's just a tiny detail missing, but I can't figure it out. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://www.mystore.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

#Rewrite for product.php?id=1
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+) product.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Without `/` before `REQUEST_URI`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Croises, but I'm afraid this didn't solve the problem.  I'm still getting a 404 error.

Comment: You wrote `products` in the question, and `product` in rewrite rules. That can be the problem ?

Comment: eh no, that was a random typo on my part, but should I just keep looking for something small like that?  Meaning, in your opinion, the code should be working?

Comment: Yes, for me that look ok

Comment: Ok, then I'll keep digging around. I must have some random typo like the one you spotted before.  Thanks for the help